# Require authorization for all but the listing view in a viewset

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a `ViewSet` called `BuildViewSet`, with a bunch of detail views and one list view:

```
class BuildViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Build.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        # Do some filtering on self.queryset based on user preferences

        return super(BuildViewSet, self).list(request)

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def transition(self, request):
        …

    # And a bunch of other methods, all prefixed with @detail_route
```

I set up REST Framework so the default authorization class is `rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

However, I want my `list()` view to be available for everyone, even unauthenticated. I tried changing my `list()` method like this:

```
@list_route(permission_classes=(AllowAny,))
def list(self, request):
    …
```

But this seems to have no effect:

```
AppError: Bad response: 401 UNAUTHORIZED (not 200 OK or 3xx redirect for http://localhost/api/v1/builds/)
'{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Changing the `@detail_route` to `@permission_classes` like this gives the same result:

```
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def list(self, request):
    …
```

So it seems that `list_route(…)` is not the way to go, but in this case, what is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decorate the `list` method with the `@permission_classes` decorator, but the problem is that this decorator is only used for [function-based views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy). Thus, you have two choices:

1) Convert the `list` view to a function-based view.

2) Authorize all views from the viewset by setting `permission_classes = (AllowAny,)` at the class level. In order to limit access to the other views, you will have to manually check the permissions using either a decorator or by calling the `check_is_authenticated` method:

```
def check_is_authenticated(self, request):
    """
    Inspired from rest_framework.views.check_permissions
    """
    if not IsAuthenticated.has_permission(request, self):
        self.permission_denied(
            request, message=getattr(permission, 'message', None)
        )
```

Since all views that require a permission are already decorated with `@detail_route`, all you have to do is create a new `@authenticated_detail_route` decorator.

EDIT 3) Another, alternative solution would be to overload the `check_permissions` method:

```
def check_permissions(self, request):
    if self.is_request_list(request):
        return
    return super(BuildViewSet, self).check_permissions(request)
```

The implementation of the `is_request_list` method is left as an exercise to the reader :-)
(seriously though, I'm not sufficiently familiar with django-rest-framework to offer an implementation. It would probably involve checking the `request.method` attribute)

EDIT As mentioned by the OP in a comment, in `check_permissions` the `self.action` attribute holds the `"list"` method name.

Comment: As I mentioned, I already have the `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` set to `IsAuthenticated`. Using `@permission_classes` as you suggest still gives me the `Authentication credentials were not provided.` error.

Comment: Ok, I did not properly understand your question. Edited now with an alternative solution.

Comment: Point 1) is against the development methods we use (although it is not impossible to convince the other devs). Going with number 2 would mean that I have to decorate all methods except `list`, which is a bit against DRY.

Comment: I see. I edited my answer to give alternative suggestions. It seems to me that since you use the detail_route decorator, you could replace it with a new authenticated_detail_route decorator.

Comment: It works like charm, thank you! Just an info: during `check_pemission()`, `self.action` holds the method name (in my case, `list`) that will be called for this specific request.